# JavaPNS via Apache Web Proxy

Tags: apple-push-notifications, javapns

My push java app is behind a web proxy. I used below code to set proxy:

ProxyManager.setProxy("", "");

After executed, I got:

javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException: Communication exception: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Proxy Error"

Please guide me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a username and password required for the proxy, then you also need to set the `proxyAuthorization` of the [`ProxyManager`](https://javapns.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/javadoc/index.html).
To encode the username and password, you can use the existing `encodeProxyAuthorization` method of the `ProxyManager`:

```
String encodeProxyAuthorization = ProxyManager.encodeProxyAuthorization(username, password);
ProxyManager.setProxyAuthorization(encodeProxyAuthorization);
```